# CSS: workaround for backface-visibility bug in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, iframe, visibility

I have a container that loads content on both sides and flips over after a certain amount of time. When the element in front is empty, the element in the back is visible in Chrome when there's an iFrame loaded in it, which is obviously a bug, as -webkit-backface-visibility should prevent this.

http://jsbin.com/beqafotu/1/edit
*works in Firefox, but not in Chrome*

Is there an easy way to work around this? I need the content to load and display in the back before it flips to the front for performance reasons, so I don't want to change the timing.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the iframe in advance, but the video will start playing before you flip it.

This could have been prevented if the video was an HTML5 video instead of an iframe since HTML5 videos can be paused using then the `.pause()` method and the `.play()` method can be called when the user flips the container.

[Here is a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/beqafotu/8/edit) showing the preloaded iframe.

Comment: Nevermind the video, it's just an example. The iframe could be anything. I just don't want the backside of the element to be visible before it's flipped.